# How to append to a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Can I append to a list in a dictionary?

```
test = {'food' : 'apple'}
```

Is there a command to add `'banana'` and turn it into

```
test = { 'food': ['apple','banana'] }
```

Thank you

Comment: `test['food'].append('banana')`.

Comment: That isn't a `list`, it is a string or `str` in python. It becomes a `list` in your second example though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `dict` where the `values` are lists:

```
test = {'food' : ['apple']}
test['food'].append('banana')
```

Answer (score 5):

No, since it isn't a list in the first place.

```
test['food'] = [test['food'], 'banana']
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would just be to just make the value of your hash a list, that may contain just one element. Then for example, you might have something like this:

```
test = {'food' : ['apple']}
test['food'].append('banana')
```

Comment: +1 I think it's likely the OP was trying append, but overlooked the missing `[]`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in this case, it's pretty straightforward to deal with dictionaries of lists, since then you don't need two separate cases every time you modify an entry:

```
import collections

test = collections.defaultdict(list)

test['food'].append('apple')
test['food'].append('banana')

print test
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'food': ['apple', 'banana']})
```

Comment: It is straightforward to do this without a `defaultdict` too: `test.setdefault("food", []).append("apple")`